# LOOCV: Which Aggregation of the Performance Metric to Report?

Tags: cross-validation

The target variable is revenue, with 81 observations and 10 features.

The target distribution is such that a standard log transformation doesn't yield an approximately normal distribution, but revenue**(1/4) does. Prospective models are trained on that transformed target but evaluated on the back-transformed predicted values.

As my performance metric, I have chosen RMSLE because it is a relative measure that penalizes underestimations higher than overestimations.

LOOCV is utilized for hyper-parameter tuning, model selection, and final model validation.

But to start making decisions, I need to choose an aggregation method. Shown below is an example of the distribution of RMSLE scores:

[image: Example of RMSLE distribution for LOOCV]

My understanding is that the mean is usually reported for LOOCV. However, given this distribution would using/reporting the median or the geometric mean be more appropriate?

EDIT:

A commenter noted that a nested CV would be more appropriate here. I believe I am doing that (my apologies for not being more descriptive), but I may be mistaken:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

alpha_range = np.logspace(-2,2,20,base=10,endpoint=True)
rmsle_df_ridge = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(map(str, alpha_range)))

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X)):
    X_train = X.iloc[train_index]
    X_test = X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train = y.iloc[train_index]
    y_test = y.iloc[test_index]
    for alpha in alpha_range:
        ridge = Ridge(alpha=alpha)
        col_tf = make_column_transformer((StandardScaler(), scaler_cols), remainder='passthrough')
        pip_dt = make_pipeline(col_tf, ridge)
        pip_dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = pip_dt.predict(X_test)
        rmsle = mean_squared_log_error(y_test**4, y_pred**4)**0.5
        rmsle_df_ridge.loc[i, str(alpha)] = rmsle
```

And then plot is generated by:

```
sns.lineplot(x=np.log10(alpha_range),y=rmsle_df_ridge.mean(axis=0))
plt.title('LOOCV Ridge')
plt.ylabel('RMSLE_mean')
plt.show()
plt.clf()
print('RMSLE_mean:  ',np.min(rmsle_df_ridge.mean(axis=0)))
```

[image: RMSLE_mean vs. alpha]

So RMSLE values are stored in n x m matrix with n = # rev_obs = 81 and m = len(alpha_range) where RMSLE (i,j) represents the RMSLE obtained by training with the ith observation left out and then testing on i, while using j as the hyperparameter alpha for ridge regression. Then I aggregate using the arithmetic mean over each column to obtain mx2 matrix RMSLE_agg with rows corresponding to (alpha, RMSLE_mean_LOOCV).

If this is incorrect, please advise.

Regardless, I am still in the dark as to whether or not aggregating with the arithmetic mean- as opposed to the median or geometric mean- is most appropriate here, given the distribution of RMSLE scores as shown above.

Comment: "OOCV is utilized for hyper-parameter tuning, model selection, and final model validation." that will give an optimistically biased final performance estimate, see https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf .  With such a small dataset, you will almost certainly need to use nested cross-validattion if you want a useful perfomance estimate.

Comment: Could you report the distribution in more detail (histogram or boxplot, say) as you do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ultimately is that a distribution is more complex than a single value, and summarising a distribution as one value will always lose potentially relevant information.

Therefore the first consideration is whether you can report more detail like the histogram or boxplot.

If you must summarise as one value, I'd normally still favour the mean, because the mean gives every observation the same weight, and all the observations are reliable and informative in the sense that your cross-validation was hopefully computed correctly in all instances so that all prediction errors correctly reflect what they are supposed to reflect. The problem with the median here is that if you compare two distributions, it can happen that they have the same median, but one yields arbitrarily worse values for a minority of size up to 50%. But if you only do well for (slightly more than) half of the predictions, this is not a good prediction method.

However one can also argue that if a prediction is grossly wrong, it doesn't matter how wrong it exactly is. You'd need to define "grossly wrong" then, but one could think about computing a mean where all values larger than 3, say, are counted as 3, if you can justify 3 as a clearly too bad and useless prediction in the application of interest. It could also be that there are some unreliable observations in your data that can't really be predicted well, in which case you could consider something like a one-sided 10% trimmed mean (mean of the lower 90%). You then say "I don't care about the worst 10%, but I do care about the others". Again this requires a tuning decision.

The geometric mean is probably too dominated by differences between very small values that in most applications will not be of much practical relevance.

So every aggregation has consequences, and the choice of an aggregation method should be driven by your understanding of the application, i.e., the actual "loss" resulting from prediction errors of different sizes.